# Rails How to Render a Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently am able to render a partial in JS like so:

```
$("#cmtList_<%= @commentable.id %>").prepend("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial =>"comments/comment", :locals => {:comment => @comment})%>");
```

The above works swell for rendering/returning one new comment.

Now I want to reuse that same partial(to stay DRY), but be able to pass an array of comments as @Comments, and have Rails loop through all the @comments records (1 or more) using the same partial, I tried this but it errors:

```
$("#cmtList_<%= @commentable.id %>").prepend("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial => "comments/comment", :collection => {:comment => @comments})%>");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#cmtList_<%= @commentable.id %>").prepend("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial => "comments/comment", :collection => @comments)%>");
```

which will look for a local variable "comment".

For more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside of escape_javascript:

```
render :partial => "comments/comment", :collection => @comments
```

Docs say that this should work too (too much magic for me):

```
render @comments
```

Check "3.4.5 Rendering Collections" from here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html